# Pareto chart in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, pareto-chart

I have table and I want to take only the columns until `>80`, according to `U1`.

T1:

```
User  || C1 || C2 || C3 || C4 || C5 || Total
  U1  || 10 || 20 || 15 || 40 || 15 || 100
  U2  || 27 || 17 || 8  || 23 || 25 || 100
```

The answer that I look for is a table like this:

P1:

```
User  || C2 || C3 || C4 || C5 
  U1  || 20 || 15 || 40 || 15 
  U2  || 17 || 8  || 23 || 25
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  In addition to sample data, desired results and code improve a question.  You should also tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: I now use MS access, but colleague suggested to use Oracle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, C1+C2+C3+C4+C5 AS total
FROM t1
WHERE C1+C2+C3+C4+C5 > 80
```

Comment: TNX, but I need the columns to do another calculation.